# git customization for commits templates

Tags: git, customization

When we used SVN, we had a commit template and some error checking on it, for instance it needed to contain 3 keyword name and one of the names had to have a value.

I am looking to implement a similar configuration for commits.

Any pointers on where to start looking for such feature?

Answer (score 0):

Start reading FM about hooks in Git!